# Understanding CodeIgniter objects and multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-2

I'm working on a project in CodeIgniter 2 and now I'm stuck on the most basic of concepts.

**Model:**

Get an object array from my table which contains all rows that match a specific value for a field named `foo`.  There can be one or more rows that match.  In this example, two rows.

```
public function get_sample($foo)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('sample_db', array('foo' => $foo));

    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller:**

Assign the results and make output available to view.

```
public function view($foo)
{
    $data['array'] = $this->sample_model->get_sample($foo);

    $this->load->view('view', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
echo var_dump($array); // for testing

echo $array[1]->text
```

**`var_dump()` of `$array`:**

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#23 (4) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar"
        ["number"]=> string(4) "1234"
        ["text"]=> string(23) "This is content in 1234"
    }
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#24 (4) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar"
        ["number"]=> string(4) "9999"
        ["text"]=> string(23) "This is content in 9999"
    } 
}
```

The rendered ouput of `echo $array[1]->text;` is: `This is content in 9999`

And I understand how all that is working:  `$array[1]->text` is the content of the `text` field in the array object with the index of `1`, my second object.

However, I have a field called `number` and I want to access the object with a certain `number` and get its corresponding `text` value.

**Example:** How can I retrieve the value of `text` where the `number` is `9999`?  I cannot use `$array[1]->text` since I can never be sure of the object's position in the array.  Something like `$array['number' => '9999']->text`, but I know that's not right.  Maybe I need to loop through the array looking for a match?

This looks so simple yet everything I've tried has failed and resulted in various PHP errors.  I've been studying the PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php), but cannot seem to find anything about what I'm looking to do, or maybe I'm just misapplying what I'm reading.  Any guidance is appreciated.

In addition to an answer using best practices following the MVC model, I'm hoping for a link to the proper page in the documentation, as well as pointing out any errors in my wording/terminology above.

---

**EDIT:**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13905837/594235) contains the actual code I used to solve my problem.  Although, [Yagi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13898189/594235) was accepted because it put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using this :

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
        if ($row->number == '9999') {
            echo $row->text;
        }
    }
```

Loop through the array, and find the number object value of 9999 and get the text

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking for something like this...

```
array_filter($array, function($o){ return $o->number == 9999; } );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

**EDIT**

$o is the parameter in the callback function. each element of the array is passed to the callback function. if the function returns false, the element will be filtered out.

```
$arr = array(
    (object) array(
        'num' => 33,
        'text' => 'hello',
    ),
    (object) array(
        'num' => 44,
        'text' => 'world',
    ),
);
$filtered = array_filter($arr, function($o){ return $o->num == 33; });
echo $filtered[0]->text; // hello
```

as you stated, index will remain, so use array_values or array_shift. here's an example with function

```
function get_by_num($arr, $num){
    return array_shift(array_filter($arr, function($o) use ($num) { return $o->num == $num; }));
}
$obj = get_by_num($arr, 44);
var_dump($obj);
// object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["num"]=> int(44) ["text"]=> string(5) "world" }
```

in this case $obj will be either NULL if element is not found, or the first match. $num is transferred along so you can use any value. you can even improve it:

```
function get_first_match($arr, $field, $val){
    return array_shift(array_filter($arr, function($o) use ($field, $val) { return $o->{$field} == $val; }));
}
$obj = get_first_match($arr, 'num', 44);
```

and now you can search any field. in your case

```
$obj = get_first_match($array, 'number', 9999);
```

Comment: `echo $filtered[0]->text;` is giving a `Undefined offset: 0` error.

Comment: then you must have done something wrong... code is fine if element is found. if it's not found the $filtered would be empty and you'll get the warning. in our case it works

Comment: `var_dump($filtered)` is returning an array that contains a single object, `array(1) { [1]=> object(stdClass)#24...`.  So actually `echo $filtered[1]->text` works but that puts me back at square one since that's the same index I was using in my original example.

Comment: run array_values on it, i'll add it underneath

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just to a query and search for that number (or order by that number?)

Either way, what you need is a multidimensional array search function (that iterates through array of object and returns the found field value combo )

Something like this (put this in helper)

```
function multi_array_search($array, $field, $value) 
 { 
     $results = array(); 

     if (is_array($array)) 
     { 
         if ($array->$field == $value)  //chek the filed against teh value, you can do addional check s(i.e. if field has been set)

             $results[] = $array; 

         foreach ($array as $subarray) 
             $results = array_merge($results,  multi_array_search($subarray, $key, $value));  //recurisve serach
     } 

     return $results; 
 }


    //than in view or in controller, depending where you need it

   $result  = multi_array_search($array, "number", "9999");
```

`var_dump($result`) will return or whether number of foudn instances

```
array() {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#24 (4) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar"
        ["number"]=> string(4) "9999"
        ["text"]=> string(23) "This is content in 9999"
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Yagi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13898189/594235), I came up with the following very simple solution.  I loop through the array and assign the value of `text` to a new array with an index that matches the value of `number`.  Then in the view file, I can access the `text` value based on this index.

**Controller:**

```
public function view($foo)
{
    $data['array'] = $this->sample_model->get_sample($foo);

    foreach ($data['array'] as $row) {
        $data['result'][$row->number] = $row->text;
    };

    $this->load->view('view', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
if (isset($result[9999])) echo $result[9999];
```